# Excel, compare cells in different sheets in a workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, comparison

I am a real nooby and I have some questions.

I have 5 sheets (A,B,C,D,E). Each sheet has numbers in it (10 rows-15 lines)  A1 to I15

Now I want to make a 6th sheet in which I can compare the cell values (higher, same, lower) for sheet A and B or C and G or A and H.

( i can do that now by changing the content of all cells from  =sheetA!A1-sheetB!A1 to =sheetA!C1-sheetB!G1 etcetera and than conditional formating. )

But I want to do that more dynamically by filling in only two cells on sheet 6, the content of that cell should be used by the others cells, like if I wanted to compare sheet C en H, the first cell would read =sheetC!A1-sheetH!A1 instead of =sheetA!A1-sheetB!A1 and second cell would read =sheetC!A2-sheetH!A2.

I know I described this not perfectly , but I hope you get the idea and can help me out !
Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make it really flexible, you might opt for `INDIRECT`, used in this way:

```
=INDIRECT("'sheet"&A17&"'!A1")-INDIRECT("'sheet"&B17&"'!A1")
```

Where, if you put `A` in A17 of the 6th sheet, and `B` in B17 of the same sheet, your formula will compare the sheetA A1 value with the sheetB A1 value.

If you change A17 to B and B17 to A, it will swap the values around. You can of course put C, D or E in those two cells.

If you want to put the whole sheet name, the formula becomes:

```
=INDIRECT("'"&A17&"'!A1")-INDIRECT("'"&B17&"'!A1")
```

And you put `sheetA` and `sheetB` instead in cells A17 and B17.

*However*, this flexibility comes at a price, called volatility; meaning that these functions will recalculate at even the smallest change in the workbook and if you have a lot of them, or have a bulky workbook, the difference is hard to ignore.

You might opt, in such cases, for a bit less flexibility, if you have specific formulae, for example, if you can have only a limited number of evaluations, you can use `CHOOSE` with a certain key number:

```
=CHOOSE(A17, sheetA!A1-sheetB!A1, sheetC!A1-sheetD!A1, ... )
```

And you can add on more calculations. In this case, `sheetA!A1-sheetB!A1` will be evaluated if there is `1` in A17.

`sheetC!A1-sheetD!A1` will be evaluated if A17 has 2. The next one will be evaluated if A17 has 3, etc.

Comment: That looks promissing ! I have to try out your solutions. Thanks for your quick and complete answer !

Comment: HI Jerry, It does what I hoped it could do. But I have an additional Question.  I wanted to copy the formula into all cells on sheet 6, but when I do that by pulling the the cells to the right or down, the wrong cells are changed. =INDIRECT("'sheet"&A17&"'!A1")-INDIRECT("'sheet"&B17&"'!A1") becomes =INDIRECT("'sheet"&B17&"'!A1")-INDIRECT("'sheet"&C17&"'!A1"), Any way to change this, so I don't have to change 150 cells manual?

Comment: ( so at the way i tried it, the cells A17 and B17 are changed instead of A1 to B1 or A1 to A2 etcetera.

Comment: @robert Oh, well, you can use `CELL` if you want Excel to fill the area properly: `INDIRECT("'sheet"&A17&"'!"&CELL("address",A1))-INDIRECT("'sheet"&B17&"'!"CELL("address",A1))`. Thing is that `CELL("address",A1)` returns A1 (or strictly speaking `$A$1` but that's not a problem here) and since it is in a function, the reference changes accordingly.

Comment: Hi Jerry , sorry for not responding quicker, I tried it but didn't work out. It gives an error (yes I added the = upfront) After telling me there is an error "address,A1" is blacked out in the bar and a box is shown beneath it with:  INDIRECT(verw_tekst;[A1]   (I have a Dutch interface and don't seem to be able to change that )

Comment: @robert It's okay. Did you try to type the whole formula from the start? Copy/pasting formulas from comments often return errors if they split onto two or more lines =/

Comment: found the translation for verw_tekst  is ref_txt.

Comment: This is the typed in formula =INDIRECT("'Comp"&F8&"'!"&CELL("address",C3))-INDIRECT("'Comp"&J8&"'!"CELL("address",C3))    The values in the sheets start at C3, the sheets are called Comp1,Comp2 etc, I changed A17 for F8 and B17 for J8 . The brackets() around "address",C3 are green, F8 is blue, J8 is black?

Comment: I noticed you used &CELL in the first and CELL (without the &) in the second part ?

Comment: To make things easier I now made sure the sheets 1-5 and sheet 6 have the same positions for the cells, so now C7 is the start in every sheet. And the source cells are F3 and J3 (instead of A17 and B17)

Comment: =INDIRECT("'Comp"&F3&"'!"&CEL("ADRES"))-INDIRECT("'Comp"&J3&"'!"&CEL("ADRES")) Ended up with this formula in all cells,the formula is excepted but the outcome is 0. Evaluation shows the right figures, but at the end the outcome is always 0! evaluation shows 10-_8_ (last figure is italic) and next step gives 0

Comment: @robert oops, yes, there should have been an `&` up there. Was typing from my phone :s `CELL` takes 2 arguments. Anyway, I have put an example [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oec8cLzld9QSEhuFhnsDjaH-YJ8qRzZzdpuCA8Q8ttU/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I have tried everything but ended up copy and pasting , and search 'n replacing to get it working. ( used # instead of = when copy 'n pasting to keep cell's values the same) It works!   Final formula i used was this: =INDIRECT("'Comp"&F2&"'!C7")-INDIRECT("'Comp"&J2&"'!C7") Many Thanks to You !!

Comment: @robert Okay, glad that you got that solved :)

Comment: Thank You. Can't upvote you or your answers, cause I don't seem to have the rights. Pitty, you deserve my vote !

Comment: @robert you can mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the tick outline below the up/down vote arrows. :)